# Is it possible to show terrain maps with Android MapView class

Tags: android, android-mapview, terrain

Is it possible to show terrain maps similar to this http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=45.699466,6.389236&spn=0.327066,0.861053&t=p&z=11 using MapView class?

Comment: Google does not expose a lot their Map features, it's too bad but the answer is no until they update the android API to take advantage of that (and about a dozen other features)

Answer (score 1):

You can swap styles of the map with `.setSatellite(true or false);` `true` for sattelite map `false` for road map. This style of map is not supported, yet.