# How to display terrain view of google map in android2.2 application?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using google maps in my **android2.2** application. In **com.google.android.maps.MapView** class i found only 2 views satellite view and street view. But, when i am browsing google maps i found **terrain** as one more view offered when we are **displaying map as street view**.

I searched many posts in internet, but all are talking about **terrain view of google maps in iPhone**.

Is it possible to display terrain view in android2.2? If yes please reply me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your classname is wrong. It should be **com.google.android.maps.MapView**. Secondly - No, this is not possible:

See:

1. [Is it possible to show terrain maps with Android MapView class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795705/is-it-possible-to-show-terrain-maps-with-android-mapview-class)
2. http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#setSatellite%28boolean%29

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i saw terrain view in android default app **Maps**.

Comment: You may have seen it, but it isn't available in the API. I also note this is the same answer you've already been given as you posed this question on a google maps newsgroup (discernible by the carbon copy of the original question here right down to the exact language and sentence structure, and proximity in date to the original question).

Answer (score 0):

This view is available in at least version 3 of the Api but you would have to build your own app to use it however there is an app on the play store for android 4.0 + that has all the views https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bodo.terrainmap